# Scrapy Error : HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed

Tags: python, scrapy

i have a problem when run the spider . when i crawl it , it's shown eror like this : "HTTP status code is not handled".

```
2018-08-27 14:30:58 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET http://id.priceprice.com/harga-hp/%3Ca%20href=%22/harga-hp/?maker=OPPO-182%22%3EOPPO%3C/a%3E> (referer: http://id.priceprice.com/harga-hp/)
2018-08-27 14:30:58 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <404 http://id.priceprice.com/harga-hp/%3Ca%20href=%22/harga-hp/?maker=OPPO-182%22%3EOPPO%3C/a%3E>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2018-08-27 14:30:58 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET http://id.priceprice.com/harga-hp/%3Ca%20href=%22/harga-hp/?maker=Smartfren-178%22%3ESmartfren%3C/a%3E> (referer: http://id.priceprice.com/harga-hp/)
2018-08-27 14:30:58 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET http://id.priceprice.com/harga-hp/%3Ca%20href=%22/harga-hp/?maker=Evercoss-184%22%3EEvercoss%20Evercoss%3C/a%3E> (referer: http://id.priceprice.com/harga-hp/)
2018-08-27 14:30:58 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET http://id.priceprice.com/harga-hp/%3Ca%20href=%22/harga-hp/?maker=Nokia-109%22%3ENokia%3C/a%3E> (referer: http://id.priceprice.com/harga-hp/)
2018-08-27 14:30:58 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET http://id.priceprice.com/harga-hp/%3Ca%20href=%22/harga-hp/?maker=HUAWEI-69%22%3EHUAWEI%3C/a%3E> (referer: http://id.priceprice.com/harga-hp/)
2018-08-27 14:30:58 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <404 http://id.priceprice.com/harga-hp/%3Ca%20href=%22/harga-hp/?maker=Smartfren-178%22%3ESmartfren%3C/a%3E>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2018-08-27 14:30:58 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <404 http://id.priceprice.com/harga-hp/%3Ca%20href=%22/harga-hp/?maker=Evercoss-184%22%3EEvercoss%20Evercoss%3C/a%3E>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
```

i have follow another instruction for edit setting.py and add code :

```
user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1207.1 Safari/537.1"
```

but its still not working .

this is my code :

```
import scrapy
from handset.items import HandsetItem
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import Rule, CrawlSpider


class HandsetpriceSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'price'
    allowed_domains = ['id.priceprice.com']
    start_urls = ['http://id.priceprice.com/harga-hp/']

    def parse(self, response):

        rules = (
                Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='div.listCont:nth-child(2) > ul:nth-child(1)'), callback='parse_details'),
                Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_css='ul > li > a[href*="maker"]'), follow =True)                
               )
        for url in  response.xpath('//ul[1]//li/a[contains(@href, "maker")]').extract() :
            url = response.urljoin(url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback = self.parse_details)

        next_page_url = response.css('li.last > a::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if next_page_url:
           next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
           yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page_url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_details(self, response):
        yield {
       'Name' : response.css('div.itmName h3:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(1) ::text').extract_first(),
       'Price' : response.css('div.itmPrice > a.price ::text').extract_first(),
        }
```

Comment: if you're getting a 404 error then the URL you're trying to scrape does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector gets to much from the url:

```
scrapy shell http://id.priceprice.com/harga-hp/

In [3]: response.xpath('//ul[1]//li/a[contains(@href, "maker")]').extract()
Out[3]: 
['<a href="/harga-hp/?maker=OPPO-182">OPPO</a>',
 '<a href="/harga-hp/?maker=Vivo-466">Vivo</a>',
 '<a href="/harga-hp/?maker=Vivo-466">Vivo</a>',
....
```

So the a href and the name is included in the link. 
Slicing out only the link part:

```
In [4]: response.xpath('//ul[1]//li/a[contains(@href, "maker")]').css('a::attr(href)').extract()
Out[4]: 
['/harga-hp/?maker=OPPO-182',
 '/harga-hp/?maker=Vivo-466',
 '/harga-hp/?maker=Vivo-466',
```

and using this selector in your code and you get:

```
2018-08-27 04:53:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://id.priceprice.com/harga-hp/?maker=Meizu-95>
{'Name': 'Meizu M6', 'Price': '\nRp 1.150.000\n - '}


{'Name': 'Infinix HOT 6 Pro', 'Price': '\nRp 1.599.000\n - '}
```

Comment: okey thanks sir , i can do it . but how can i make the rule for the link, so if i scrawl it just shown different maker not the same maker . using deny , or deny_domains, or deny_extensions?

Comment: Can you please explain in examples what you want to get?

Comment: The duplicates are usually filtered by scrapy. So you don't need to bother about that.

Comment: okey then thanks before sir . so i have one more question about it . can i ask you?